# Selenium web tests don't run as expected

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, m2eclipse

I have never looked into this before but have an existing project that I would like to run and then add som extra features to.

I have installed as follows:

-Eclipse Kepler 
-Java JDK
-Maven 3.3.9 
-Maven plugin in Eclipse
-Selenium IDE in Firefox
-Cucumberplugin in Eclipse

The "project" is successfully built running for example "Eclipse -> Run As-> Maven clean" or "cmd -> mvn validate".

I can run the "project" with for example "Eclipse -> Run As-> Maven test".

When I run the "project":
-The .java class enters the @Before method which opens my browser of selection according to the WebDriver used.
-The .java class enters the @Given method and opens the correct URL.

After this there are a lot of @When and @Then and more @Given, but these never seem to be executed. For example, the next thing that should happen is that some input should be made and a button being clicked but nothing happens. When I close the browser the Eclipse -> Console shows all the features in the .feature file (Test Project/src/test/resources/com/company/test) followed by the error below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at com.company.test.WebTestSteps.AssertExists(WebTestSteps.java:81)
    at com.company.test.WebTestSteps.I_should_be_on_the_page(WebTestSteps.java:180)
    at ?.Then I should be on the "Please login using your account information" page(com/company/test/OpenAllWindows.feature:6)

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 103 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'Hafjall', ip: '192.168.2.204', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=C:\Users\User~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7884_25604}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=53.0.2785.116, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 37a0d1f5514c5f53158d6742152a5337
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:610)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
    at com.company.test.WebTestSteps.tearDown(WebTestSteps.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:30)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:221)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:209)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runAfterHooks(Runtime.java:203)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:83)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:40)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Tests run: 496, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 492, Time elapsed: 34.881 sec <<< FAILURE!
Then I should be on the "Please login using your account information" page(Scenario: Test)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at com.company.test.WebTestSteps.AssertExists(WebTestSteps.java:81)
    at com.company.test.WebTestSteps.I_should_be_on_the_page(WebTestSteps.java:180)
    at ?.Then I should be on the "Please login using your account information" page(com/company/test/OpenAllWindows.feature:6)

Scenario: Test  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at com.company.test.WebTestSteps.AssertExists(WebTestSteps.java:81)
    at com.company.test.WebTestSteps.I_should_be_on_the_page(WebTestSteps.java:180)
    at ?.Then I should be on the "Please login using your account information" page(com/company/test/OpenAllWindows.feature:6)

Scenario: Test  Time elapsed: 0.244 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 103 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'Hafjall', ip: '192.168.2.204', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.24.417431 (9aea000394714d2fbb20850021f6204f2256b9cf), userDataDir=C:\Users\User~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7884_25604}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=53.0.2785.116, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 37a0d1f5514c5f53158d6742152a5337
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:610)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
    at com.company.test.WebTestSteps.tearDown(WebTestSteps.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:30)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:221)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:209)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runAfterHooks(Runtime.java:203)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:50)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:83)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:40)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  Then I should be on the "Please login using your account information" page(Scenario: Test)
  Scenario: Test
  Scenario: Test: chrome not reachable(..)

Tests run: 496, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 492

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.085 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-16T09:15:16+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/250M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project WebTests: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to E:\WebTest\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: It seems that is uses chrome. Do you have Chrome installed? Did you start the selenium server with chromedriver?

Comment: Yes I have Chrome installed and the chromedriver is in the bin folder. That actually works. Chrome is opened with the right URL but then nothing happens. I have tried with different browsers. The "Before" and "Given" runs but it never reaches the "When" that should be hit and prefill some inputs and click a button.